# Get all product images, including excluded images

Tags: magento

I've been using getMediaGalleryImages,  but I just realized that doesn't return excluded images.  Is there another similar method that does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$product = $this->getProduct();
$galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');
```

Something like above code will get all Media images for a product.

Comment: is there a way to get the same thing for configurable products because this function does not return the value_id I need.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but others may want to try

```
$product->getMediaGallery('images')
```

for getting all images in an array, including the ones marked with 'exclude'.

Comment: its not working form me.. i tried as follows but not showing excluded image in array
<?php 
                     $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product)->getMediaGalleryImages('images');
            ?>
            <?php 
                     if($_images){?>          
            <?php  $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++;?>
          
            <img src="<?=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image', $_image->getFile()); ?>" />
                    
            <?php  } ?>
            <?php  } ?>

Answer (score 1):

If You use custom collection try to add this:

```
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
```