# get only excluded product images

Tags: php, magento

I was searching for same and found this code

```
$product->getMediaGallery('images');
```

to get all images **[including excluded images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19524319/725306)** of products. I'd not tested the above code but what I need is to get only the excluded images. Is there any way? Also, how can I select images from label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://magentotutorialbeginners.blogspot.in/2014/03/get-product-image-from-label-magento.html

you can exclude the image from label this way

```
 $image= Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages();

 $_images = $image->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'YOUR_LABEL');
```

**EDIT** ***to get exclude image***

When you look at `class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` in `getMediaGalleryImages()`

```
if(!$this->hasData('media_gallery_images') && is_array($this->getMediaGallery('images'))) {
            $images = new Varien_Data_Collection();
            foreach ($this->getMediaGallery('images') as $image) {
                if ($image['disabled']) {
                    continue; ***//HERE Magento remove disbale image so you can hack this or override this***
                }
                $image['url'] = $this->getMediaConfig()->getMediaUrl($image['file']);
                $image['id'] = isset($image['value_id']) ? $image['value_id'] : null;
                $image['path'] = $this->getMediaConfig()->getMediaPath($image['file']);
                $images->addItem(new Varien_Object($image));
            }
            $this->setData('media_gallery_images', $images);
        }
```

Comment: and for excluded images?

Comment: excluded images means i didn't get it properly.Can you please more elaborate

Comment: while adding product images in admin there's an option to exclude images. so, i want to get only those images which are marked as excluded

Comment: `$image->getItemByColumnValue('label', 'YOUR_LABEL');` seems to match the exact value for label. is there any way which will work like `like` in mysql

Comment: if I be overriding that block then how will I get label of that image? (no filter based on label)

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because from the point of view of creating a custom module you should override blocks, models, etc. rather than writing a custom code in your template file. the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22251326/725306) is also helpful

Answer (score 3):

```
$prod = 4542;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod);

foreach ($product->getMediaGallery('images') as $img) {
    if ($img['disabled'] == 1) {
        var_dump($img['label']);
    }


}
```

Comment: ok. this seems to be good as I seen in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` there in `getMediaGalleryImages()` used the same trick to remove excluded images. but how will i get label of them?

Comment: var_dump($img['label']);

Comment: its not working showing empty results  : string(0) ""